# Netbeans PHP function parameter hints

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, code-completion, code-hinting

I looked around and found things that addressed related issues, but not what I'm looking for specifically.

I'm using Netbeans which has really grown on me, but when I go to use a function, the "intellisense" hints pop up correctly, but as soon as I go to type in the arguments, the code hint that shows the function signature and its parameters disappear.

This hurts my productivity because I don't have the signatures memorized, and I always end up having to reference it as I'm typing it up.

Is this normal for Netbeans or is there some way I can make it so the function hints stay until I close the parenthesis for the function signature?

**Update:**  I just found Ctrl + P will show the parameter methods, is there some way to have that automatically show instead of constantly typing Ctrl + P?

Comment: In my NetBeans 7.3 if there is only the opening bracket for example `substr(` and than start writing the parameters are shown.

Comment: @DavidTorrey I use Ctrl + Space on the function name to bring up the intellisense window

Comment: i have brackets as auto-closing so i guess i'll have to turn that off and see if it works

Comment: thanks.  sorta works. still doesn't pop up until i start typing in a parameter but it at least shows now.  appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently turning off auto-bracket closing will allow intellisense and code hints to appear correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Inside function parentheses, type *Ctrl + P* and  the parameters hint will appear (*NetBeans Menu Bar -> Source -> Show Method Parameters*).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Not sure why someone rated it down. Tnks!

Comment: rated down? why? bizarre. this is the correct answer.